# how do i use the set_index command in an existing Pandas Code

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pycharm

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("ascacasa.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv("cascsaca.csv")
```

how can i use this command >set_index('Hour') in the existing python code?

my Idea was the following

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    df1 = pd.read_csv("ascacasa.csv")
    df1 = pd.set_index('HOUR')
 
    df2 = pd.read_csv("cascsaca.csv")
    df2 = pd.set_index('HOUR')
```

but that doesnt work. If i try it with >index_col=''< it also doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should've been

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("ascacasa.csv")
df1 = df1.set_index('HOUR')

df2 = pd.read_csv("cascsaca.csv")
df2 = df2.set_index('HOUR')
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("ascacasa.csv", index_col="HOUR")
df2 = pd.read_csv("cascsaca.csv", index_col="HOUR")
```

Comment: for both df1 and df2? should i write it below each code pasage?